# In Javascript/Coffeescript how can I mock out a module's public function in a test?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, mocking, module-pattern

This is just like [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416392/in-javascript-coffeescript-how-can-i-mock-out-a-modules-public-variable-in-a-te) but this is about functions instead of variables.  I've got a module and I want to mock out a function in it.  Here's my coffeescript code:

```
root = exports ? this

root.prod = (->
  iWantToBeMocked = -> alert "production"
  doSomething = -> iWantToBeMocked()

  return {
    doSomething: doSomething
    iWantToBeMocked: iWantToBeMocked
  }
)()

root.test = (->
  root.prod.iWantToBeMocked = -> alert "I mocked this"
  root.prod.doSomething()

  return {}
)()
```

This alerts "production" but I want it to alert "I mocked this".  How can I do this?

Here's the javascript that gets output:

```
var root;

root = typeof exports !== "undefined" && exports !== null ? exports : this;

root.prod = (function() {
  var doSomething, iWantToBeMocked;
  iWantToBeMocked = function() {
    return alert("production");
  };
  doSomething = function() {
    return iWantToBeMocked();
  };
  return {
    doSomething: doSomething,
    iWantToBeMocked: iWantToBeMocked
  };
})();

root.test = (function() {
  root.prod.iWantToBeMocked = function() {
    return alert("I mocked this");
  };
  root.prod.doSomething();
  return {};
})();
```

---

### Update

I've figured out how to solve my problem on my own by applying the answer for my original question:

```
root = exports ? this

root.prod = (->
  iWantToBeMocked = -> alert "production"
  doSomething = -> this.iWantToBeMocked()

  return {
    doSomething: doSomething
    iWantToBeMocked: iWantToBeMocked
  }
)()

root.test = (->
  root.prod.iWantToBeMocked = -> alert "I mocked this"
  root.prod.doSomething()

  return {}
)()
```

Notice the `this` in this line: `doSomething = -> this.iWantToBeMocked()`.  But there's still a question here to be answered.  I don't understand why I have to use `this` here.  I'd like someone to explain to me the difference between `doSomething = -> this.iWantToBeMocked()` and `doSomething = -> iWantToBeMocked()` in the context of mocking.

Comment: Are you using any kind of testing framework? I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Mathletics I'm not using a testing framework.  I'm trying to test this using pure javascript right now because I don't want to automate this test.  I'm at a very experimental stage of game development and I need to see the results and tinker with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `prod` object, you have **2** objects with the name `iWantToBeMocked`. The first is the variable containing the function with your original alert; the second is contained in the returned object.

The `var iWantToBeMocked` *inside* `root.prod` is a private variable. When you set `root.prod.iWantToBeMocked`, you are changing the returned function but are not touching the private member.

Now, when you use

```
doSomething = -> this.iWantToBeMocked()
```

`doSomething` will look for a method attached to the context `this` which happens to be `root.prod`, so instead of calling the *private* `iWantToBeMocked` it will call `root.prod.iWantToBeMocked`.